# how can i stop looping once all the slide done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="mySlides">
</div>
<div class="mySlides">
</div>
<div class="mySlides">
</div>
<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
</script>
```

> i wrote this script for changing the div but this is looping how to stop looping once all dives are over

Comment: count number of slides and stop it when it reaches that count

Comment: What does it mean "once all the dives are over"? If they are "over" then stop looping them by returning from the function or by some simple _if_ statemen (And there are other options BTW). This question is unclear

Comment: check this https://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/Image%20Slider/.

Comment: Lists in JavaScript are 0-based, so you probably want to initialize `slideIndex` to 0, not 1...

Comment: thank you for your replay..i am calling that script with onclick="plusDivs(-1)"  so  the divs are repeating i am trying to stop repeating the divs @SudharshanNair

Comment: thank you for your replay..i am calling that script with onclick="plusDivs(-1)" so the divs are repeating i am trying to stop repeating the divs  @HereticMonkey

Answer (score 0):

Well to be honest I have no clue what you wrote down. But I'm a starting javascript developer, so that could be my fault. If I try to run your code in my browser it won't even work.

Try to use explanatory variable names, so instead of "x" use "slide". This will make it much more easier to change your code later on. Especially when it becomes bigger and bigger.

For the fun I tried to recreate your idea with the knowledge I have right now. I hope you could learn from it:

```
<div class="mySlides" style="display: bloc;">
  test1
</div>
<div class="mySlides" style="display: none;">
  test2
</div>
<div class="mySlides" style="display: none">
  test3
</div>

<script>
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".mySlides");
const amountOfSlides = slides.length;
let nextSlide = 1;

const slideShow = setInterval(function(){
    if(nextSlide !== amountOfSlides){
      slides[nextSlide - 1].style.display = "none";
      slides[nextSlide].style.display = "block";
      nextSlide++
    }else{
      console.log("Amount of slides reached");
      clearInterval(slideShow);

      // If you want to repeat the slideshow
      // you just have to reset the settings:

      // slides[nextSlide-1].style.display = "none";
      // slides[0].style.display = "block";
      // nextSlide = 1;
    }
  },3000);
</script>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZqGNBx

I hope it'll help you out further!

Comment: i am calling that script with onclick="plusDivs(-1)"  so  the divs are repeating i am trying to stop repeating the divs @melvin idema

Comment: To understand the script you should have basic knowledge of Javascript and - correct me if I'm wrong - that knowledge is not yours yet. This script is taken from W3 ORG and in my opinion very confusing for beginners. Start with a javascript tutorial to really understand the basics. I, sadly, can't help you with this script. I have no clue what you mean or why it would loop. The script is very confusing, at least for me as a starting developer.